# how to hide picture from gallery but show in storage of system?

Tags: android, gallery

I have an application that download picture from internet.I want when download picture don't show in gallery but show in SD card and folder because the user can delete the file.
Like of telegram.
When i add . first of name of file hide from everywhere

Comment: There are ~2 billion Android devices, spread across thousands of device models from hundreds of manufacturers. There will be dozens, if not hundreds, of pre-installed gallery applications on those devices. Users can also download other gallery applications. There is no guaranteed means of hiding something from all those applications, while simultaneously still allowing other things (including the user) to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code:

```
private void createNoMedia() {
        final File nomedia = new File(getConversationsFileDirectory()+".nomedia");
        if (!nomedia.exists()) {
            try {
                nomedia.createNewFile();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(Config.LOGTAG, "could not create nomedia file");
            }
        }
    }

public static String getConversationsFileDirectory() {
        return  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/YourFolder/";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1. Download a image file using your application instead of using default download manager API.
2. Save a file with a different extension which is not jpg or png or any other image ext.
3. Only your app can understand the extension and display it as a image.